# Android Studio Giraffe crash suspect related to icons or assets

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, assets

It is **android studio** itself crash, not **app** crash.
How I catch the problem and suspect icons/assets related:

- I created a new project, then clicked **split** (code/split/design),
  it crashed. (Gradle building is ok, it crashes when running compose-function rendering preview)
- I opened the **AndroidManifest.xml**, it crashed. So, I edited **AndroidManifest.xml**
  in NotePad, and found out it won't crash if I deleted statements `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` and `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"`.
- I edited **ic_launcher.xml** in NotePad, kept only `<adaptive-icon> </adaptive-icon>`, it crashed.
- I edited **ic_launcher_background.xml** in NotePad, kept only `<vector> </vector>`, it crashed.
- I open **Resource Manager**, it crashed.
- If not split/open .xml/..., the new created project running ok on the Emulator.

I am using win10(and tried win11), I have also tried **Hedgehog Beta** and **Iguana Canary**, they both crashed as **Giraffe**. I have tried old version **Bumblebee Canary 11** as well, it did NOT crash.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!